# windows batch file script to sort URLs

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I write a windows batch script to sort URLs by grouping those with unique file names together in a text file? I don't know how to describe further what I want to achieve but I hope the example below explains everything:

I want this text

```
http://example.com/5235/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/2725/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/4627/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/8385/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/3886/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/5896/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/2788/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/1758/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/1788/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/1567/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/8065/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/6467/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/1464/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/6581/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/4642/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/8635/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/2578/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/1452/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/8652/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/9463/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/9765/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/3578/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/3583/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/9467/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/3683/Mango.jpg
http://example.com/3479/Mango.jpg
http://example.com/1795/Mango.jpg
http://example.com/7345/Mango.jpg
```

sorted this way

```
http://example.com/5235/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/3886/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/1788/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/1464/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/2578/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/9765/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/3683/Mango.jpg
http://example.com/2725/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/5896/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/1567/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/6581/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/1452/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/3578/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/3479/Mango.jpg
http://example.com/4627/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/2788/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/8065/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/4642/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/8652/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/3583/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/1795/Mango.jpg
http://example.com/8385/Guava.jpg
http://example.com/1758/Lemon.jpg
http://example.com/6467/Apple.jpg
http://example.com/8635/Banana.jpg
http://example.com/9463/Pineapple.jpg
http://example.com/9467/Peach.jpg
http://example.com/7345/Mango.jpg
```

In other words, for this particular example (withe four of each fruit jpeg) I want to sort lines according to this manner: 1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, and so on. I hope you get what I mean.

The text file always contains urls with the same number of every "fruit" picture. There can't be six lemon jpg files and four guava jpg files. I hope you get what I what I mean.

Comment: This is a programming task, not a question. Do you expect people to write the code for you?

Comment: i thought a simple code will accomplish this task.

Comment: It's probably a simple code if you do it in some high-level language like Python (although I'm not even sure about that). This is not a standard task.

Comment: No, this is a very easy task. Not a one-liner, though. Here's a hint: Take the first line and grep | wc -l to see how many there are of it. You say there have to be the same number of each, so now we know how many "units" there are. Now `uniq` it to see what the unique lines are. Echo them out to a file "count" times, where "count" is the wc -l output from before.

Comment: @Drysdam Can you write it please? Please, I need it badly.

Comment: @drysdam: You can't rely on the name of the first line or name of any of the lines because they vary. The truth is I want to sort URLs and I only used fruits to represent them. The URLs vary but the file names don't. For example, http://example.com/83yhrf98/guava.jpg and another "guava" url can be http://example.com/23fasUan/guava.jpg but the links are originally sorted by filenames i.e. the 29th character of each of the URL.

Comment: I think you better edit the question to have real(er) data. The given algorithm will still work, but it needs tweaking to find the final filename.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET origfile=urls.txt
SET c=1
SET skip=4
FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,%skip%) DO IF EXIST %origfile%.%%c DEL %origfile%.%%c
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (%origfile%) DO CALL :process "%%L"
DEL %origfile%
FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,%skip%) DO (
  TYPE %origfile%.%%c >> %origfile%
  DEL %origfile%.%%c
)
GOTO :EOF

:process
ECHO %~1>>%origfile%.%c%
SET /A c=c%%skip+1
```

The idea is to output subsequent lines to different files, repeating the sequence every 4 lines (and 4 is parametrised here actually, so you can easily change it), then concatenate those files under the original name.

Comment: neat approach doing a modulo.

Comment: Wow! Works just how I need it to work! Thank you very much! @Andriy M

Answer (score 1):

Run this on your file. Algorithm as described in my comment above.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
FIRST=$(head -1 $FILE)
COUNT=$(grep $FIRST $FILE | wc -l)
LINES=$(uniq $FILE)
for i in $(seq 1 $COUNT); do
    echo $LINES | tr " " "\n"
done
```

Comment: unfortunately, i am looking for a windows batch script. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `sort` where to start comparing:

```
/+n                         Specifies the character number, n, to
                            begin each comparison.  /+3 indicates that
                            each comparison should begin at the 3rd
                            character in each line.  Lines with fewer
                            than n characters collate before other lines.
                            By default comparisons start at the first
```

So if your URI prefix is always the same (which your comments indicated) you can just run the file through

```
sort /+25 list.txt /O:list_new.txt
```

which should sort it by file name, then.